# How do I get all my wallet balance

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

How do I get all my wallet balance？
I already have a very large number of wallet addresses, and I need to know the balance.and I want to know the number of addresses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### With a block explorer

You can do it manually by looking up all your addresses on a block explorer (such as https://etherscan.io) and adding up the balances by hand.

#### With a script

Using geth and [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API), you could create a script to iterate through a number of addresses and sum the balances.

Here's a simple script below;

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io"));

var arrAddresses = ["0xb794f5ea0ba39494ce839613fffba74279579268", "0xe853c56864a2ebe4576a807d26fdc4a0ada51919"];
var flTotal = 0;

for(var intIteration = 0; intIteration < arrAddresses.length; intIteration++) {
  flTotal += web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(arrAddresses[intIteration]).toString(10), "ether");
}

console.log("Total Ether: "+ flTotal);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Programatically: create an [Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/myapikey) key then [use the API](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) to:**

*Get Ether Balance for a single Address*

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

*Get Ether Balance for multiple Addresses in a single call*

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balancemulti&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a,0x63a9975ba31b0b9626b34300f7f627147df1f526,0x198ef1ec325a96cc354c7266a038be8b5c558f67&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

**Manually and easier**

Just paste your addresses in this [CoinSpectator](https://coinspectator.com/eth/balances) tool.

**Both options above do not include token balances. To get token balances:**

Plug your address in the [Ethplorer tool](https://ethplorer.io/) or use their API:

```
https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/0xff71cb760666ab06aa73f34995b42dd4b85ea07b?apiKey=freekey
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
function checkAllBalances() {
     var totalBal = 0;
     for (var acctNum in eth.accounts) {
         var acct = eth.accounts[acctNum];
         var acctBal = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(acct), "ether");
         totalBal += parseFloat(acctBal);
         console.log("  eth.accounts[" + acctNum + "]: \t" + acct + " \tbalance: " + acctBal + " ether");
     }
     console.log("  Total balance: " + totalBal + " ether");
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up at etherscan.io to keep track of your addresses and balances:

1. Register at [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/)
2. Add your addresses https://etherscan.io/myaddress
3. Check bottom of your address to see total

[image: Etherscan - Addresses Watchlist]

**Bonus**:
you can also setup notifications for incoming or outgoing transactions. Plus it has number of [APIs](https://etherscan.io/apis) that you can use programmatically.